# Differences between angular.copy() and JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object, clone

Can someone explain the differences between angular.copy() and JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())? Are there any? What you will recommend to use? Is angular.fromJson(angular.toJson()) the same as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())?


Just to mention, I've read [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) for JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) and [angular.copy() reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) for angular.copy().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` won't copy:

- functions
- any object that has a special representation, like `Date` (it will get copied but not as `Date`)
- properties with the value `undefined`

`angular.fromJson(angular.toJson())` is basically the same except that `angular.toJson()` omits properties that are used by Angular internally (those starting with `$$`).

Comment: When do we need to copy only data without function reference, date, undefined values then Which is the best approach? angular.copy() or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())

Answer (score 7):

I can very specifically answer your question by pointing out they treat `undefined` differently:

```
> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(undefined))
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

And more generally I would prefer angular.copy:

- angular.copy says *exactly* what you want; JSON.parse * JSON.stringify is a hack, from a readability standpoint.
- angular.copy is almost certainly more performant since it is a higher-level specification of what you are trying to do. If the engineers who wrote it wrote something *less* performant, they would implement it with the JSON version...

*That being said*, do they treat more esoteric data, such as functions, the same way? I can't answer this off the top of my head but I would research (or wait for another answer) before deciding.

Comment: angular.copy copies the function pointer, +1 for the hack comment. Even if you deliberately want a copy without functions then I would write a function that does just that. don't litter your code base with these hacks. keep them in one place

Comment: angular.copy will also copy Date instances correctly.

Comment: Good point by Liviu T, to see the limitations of JSON.parse you should investigate what can be contained within JSON.  [w3schools json](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

Comment: Maybe they don't implement it with the JSON version because they want it to behave a bit different. So the JSON version could be faster.